# The number of ways in which a score of $11$ can be made from a throw by three persons,each throwing a single die once is

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> What is the number of ways in which a score of $11$ can be made from a throw by three persons, each throwing a single die once?

---

**My Attempt:**

I tried to answer this question by counting the possible number of occurences of dices such that their sum is $11$ without repetition of same occurrences.

$6$   $4$  $1$
$6$   $3$  $2$
$5$   $5$  $1$
$5$   $4$  $2$
$6$   $3$  $3$
$4$   $3$  $4$

So the total number of such occurrences is $6$ and these occurrences can be permuted in $3!$ ways each. So the final answer is $6 \cdot 3!$. But the correct answer is supposed to be 27, so where am I wrong?

Note: I want to solve this question by counting method only.

Comment: You can not permute, say, $(6,3,3)$ in $3!$ ways.

Comment: $633$, $551$, $434$ cannot be uniquely permuted in $3!$ ways.

Comment: @lulu I can (6,3,3)  ,(3,6,3)  ,(3,3,6)  .Am i wrong?

Comment: That is only three permutations.  $3!=6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are counting the permutations of $434$, $551$ and $633$ as six possibilities each, rather than the correct three. Thus, you must subtract nine from your total of $36$ to get the correct result of $27$.

Comment: I can (6,3,3) ,(3,6,3) ,(3,3,6) .Am i wrong?

Comment: @RadhikaT But that's all the distinct permutations you'll get for those rolls.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write every possible ways in which 11 comes keeping in mind that not repeating the digits. For example if i have counted (1,4,6) i must not count (6,4,1) and other nos. That can be formed using (1,4,6) while writing down the ways in which no. Adds up to 11. ( We will consider only when counting the total no. of possibilities.)
(1,4,6)→6 possibilities
(1,5,5)→3 possibilities
(2,3,6)→6 possibilities
(2,4,5)→6 possibilities
(3,3,5)→3 possibilities
(3,4,4)→3 possibilities
In total 27 possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

By using generating functions, we are interested in the coefficient of $t^{11}$ in the expression

$$(t+t^2+t^3 + t^4 + t^5 + t^6)^3$$

which is $27$.